# Placing camera W.R.T 3d object in three.js

Tags: javascript, vector, matrix, three.js, webgl

I have an object that moves and rotates, and I want the camera to stay a certain distance behind it. To be clear, I'm drawing an airplane and want the camera to always be looking at its rear. (Unless the user drags the mouse, for example to look at the top of the airplane as it flies).

So say I have set the position and rotation of the airplane (instance of THREE.Object3D):

```
airplane.position = {x: 1, y:2, z: 3};
airplane.rotation = {x: Math.PI/4, y:1.2, z: 0};
```

And say, when the rotation and positions are (0,0,0) the camera is at (5, 0, 0), (i.e. 5 units behind the airplane's center), what would be the simplest way of finding the position vector to set the camera at?

Thanks

Sorry for the sprawled code, I'm hacking it to death. I'd make a jsfiddle for it, but haven't got a server to host three.js on...

```
$(function(){
    var camera1, camera2, scene, renderer, viewPort;
    var objectManager;
    var views = [];
    var vpWidth, vpHeight;
    init();
    animate();
    updateSize();
    function updateSize(){
        vpWidth = viewPort.innerWidth();
        vpHeight = viewPort.innerHeight();
    }
    function init() {
        viewPort = $('#viewPort');
        objectManager = new ObjectManager();

        views[0] = new View(viewPort, objectManager);
        var view = views[0];
        view.fov = 20;
        view.proportions.height = 0.5;
        view.proportions.bottom = 0.5;
        view.init();
        views[1] = new View(viewPort, objectManager);
        var view = views[1];
        view.fov = 10;
        view.proportions.height = 0.5;
        view.init();
        view.updateCamera = function(){

            //-----------------------------------------------------
            // when the user drags the mouse, (not yet implemented)
            // the following camera position numbers would change
            // so that he could view for example the top of the
            // airplane as it flies
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            this.camera.position.set( 5,5,5 );

            //-----------------------------------------------------
            // This line does not work as expected: the airplane
            // does not stay in the center of the view but follows
            // some sort of curved path with respect to the camera
            //-----------------------------------------------------
            this.camera.lookAt(objectManager.airplane.position);

            this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        };
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        objectManager.addTo(scene);

        objectManager.airplane.add(views[1].camera);

        //-----------------------------------------------
        // The following two lines *do* work correctly //
        //-----------------------------------------------
        views[1].camera.position.set( 0,0,5 );
        views[1].camera.lookAt(objectManager.airplane.position);

        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x808080);
        scene.add(ambientLight);        

        var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x808080);
        pointLight.position = {x: 100, y: 100, z: 100};
        scene.add(pointLight);      

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColorHex(0x000000, 1);
        renderer.setSize( viewPort.innerWidth(), viewPort.innerHeight() );
        viewPort.get(0).appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        render();
    }
    function render() {
        objectManager.tick();
        var view;
        for (var i in views){
            view = views[i];
            view.updateCamera();
            pixels = view.pixels;
            renderer.setViewport(pixels.left, pixels.bottom, pixels.width, pixels.height);
            renderer.setScissor(pixels.left, pixels.bottom, pixels.width, pixels.height);
            renderer.enableScissorTest(true);
            renderer.render( scene, view.camera );
        }
    }
});
function View(vp, om){
    this.objectManager = om;
    this.viewPort = vp;
    this.fov = 30;
    this.proportions = { left: 0, bottom: 0, height: 1, width: 1 };
    this.pixels = { left: 0, bottom: 0, height: 0, width: 0, aspect: 0 };
    this.aspect;
    this.init = function(){
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 
                this.fov, 
                this.viewPort.innerWidth() / this.viewPort.innerHeight(), 
                0.1, 10000 
        );
        this.pixels.left = Math.floor(this.proportions.left * this.viewPort.innerWidth()); 
        this.pixels.width = Math.floor(this.proportions.width * this.viewPort.innerWidth()); 
        this.pixels.bottom = Math.floor(this.proportions.bottom * this.viewPort.innerHeight()); 
        this.pixels.height = Math.floor(this.proportions.height * this.viewPort.innerHeight()); 
        this.pixels.aspect = this.pixels.width / this.pixels.height;
        this.camera.position.y = 0;
        this.camera.position.z = 10;
        this.camera.aspect = this.pixels.aspect;
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    };
    this.updateCamera = function(){};
}

function newCube(dims, pos, cols, colAss){
    var mesh;
    var geometry;
    var materials = [];
    geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( dims.x, dims.y, dims.z );
    for (var i in cols){
        materials[i] = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: cols[i], ambient: cols[i], overdraw: true } );
    }
    geometry.materials = materials;
    for (var i in colAss){
        geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = colAss[i];
    }
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
    mesh.position = pos;
    return mesh;
}
function ObjectManager(){
    this.airplane;
    var fuselage;
    var tail;
    var grid;
    this.addTo = function(scene){
        this.airplane = new THREE.Object3D();
        fuselage = newCube(
                {x: 1, y: 0.1, z: 0.1}, 
                {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0},
                [0xffff00, 0x808000, 0x0000ff, 0xff00000, 0xffffff, 0x808080],
                [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        );
        this.airplane.add(fuselage);
        tail = newCube(
                {x: 0.15, y: 0.2, z: 0.05}, 
                {x: 0.5, y: 0.199, z: 0},
                [0xffff00, 0x808000, 0x0000ff, 0xff00000, 0xffffff, 0x808080],
                [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        );
        this.airplane.add(tail);
        scene.add( this.airplane );

        grid = new THREE.Object3D();

        var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( - 200, 0, 0 ) );
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 200, 0, 0 ) );

        linesMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00, opacity: 1, linewidth: .1 } );

        for ( var i = 0; i <= 200; i ++ ) {

            var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, linesMaterial );
            line.position.z = ( i * 2 ) - 200;
            grid.add( line );

            var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, linesMaterial );
            line.position.x = ( i * 2 ) - 200;
            line.rotation.y = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
            grid.add( line );
        }       
        scene.add( grid );

    };
    this.tick = function(){
        this.airplane.rotation.x += 0.005;
        this.airplane.rotation.y += 0.01;
        this.airplane.position.x += 0.01;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the camera as a child of the airplane, instead.

```
airplane.add( camera );
camera.position.set( 5, 0, 0 );
camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) );
```

Now, when you rotate/move the airplane, the camera will follow automatically.

Comment: Thanks - but this isn't working for me, it sets the camera position to (5,0,0) in world space and the camera doesn't move when I change the airplane position. (However it does stay oriented such that it looks at the same side of the airplane even when the airplane is rotated)

Comment: If the camera is a child of the airplane, then it will move when the airplane moves. Can you provide a live example?

Comment: I've posted into the question the code including your suggestion

Comment: Oh man. Too much to debug. What I posted is the solution to your question. I'll be glad to help you tomorrow... it's 2:30 am here.

Comment: I've found it works if in the main init function the calls in this order: camera.position.set(...), camera.lookAt(...), airplane.add(camera). The problem is when I want to change on each re-render the position of the camera relative to the airplane that it stops looking at the plane, and calling lookAt again results in a strange camera rotation (when placed in the view's updateCamera method)

Comment: You should not change the camera position. It will be following the airplane on it's own now.

Comment: Yes, it does follow it correctly if I set an initial offset relative to the airplane. But I also want to change the position relative to the airplane when the user drags the mouse - that isn't working. For example, the user may want to drag the mouse so he can watch the top of the airplane while it flies. Calling camera.position.set(...) + lookAt(...) after requestAnimationFrame produces strange behaviour.

Comment: You are now asking a different question. Please "accept" this answer, and if you have a new problem, please make a new post.